# Sql to find timediff between two rows based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

The subject of the question is not very explanatory, sorry for that.

Ya so the question follows:
I have a database structure as below where pk is primary key, id 
is something which is multiple for many rows.

```
+------+------+---------------------+
| pk   | id   | value               |
+------+------+---------------------+
|   99 |    1 | 2013-08-06 11:10:00 |
|  100 |    1 | 2013-08-06 11:15:00 |
|  101 |    1 | 2013-08-06 11:20:00 |
|  102 |    1 | 2013-08-06 11:25:00 |
|  103 |    2 | 2013-08-06 15:10:00 |
|  104 |    2 | 2013-08-06 15:15:00 |
|  105 |    2 | 2013-08-06 15:20:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
```

What is really need to get is, value difference between first two rows (which is ordered by value) for each
group (where group is by id). So according to above structure I need
timediff(value100, value99) [ which is for id 1 group]
and timediff(value104, value103) [ which is for id 2 group]

i.e. value difference of time ordered by value for 1st two rows in each group.

One way i can think to do is by 3 self joins (or 3 sub queries) so as to find the
first two in 2 of them , and third query subtracting it. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you need it in a single SQL instruction? can you (or would you like to) use a stored procedure?

Comment: Will love single sql solution

Comment: Just updated my example.. Please mark a answer as solution to your problem.. if any one fits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks a bit wierd... But you can try this way

```
SET @previous = 0;
SET @temp = 0;
SET @tempID = 0;
```

Above step may not be needed .. But just to make sure nothing goes wrong

```
SELECT pkid, id, diff, valtemp FROM (
SELECT IF(@previousID = id, @temp := @temp + 1, @temp := 1) occ, @previousID := id,
TIMEDIFF(`value`, @previous) diff, pk, id, `value`, @previous := `value` 
FROM testtable) a WHERE occ = 2
```

[Demo on sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bfcca/2)

Answer (score 1):

try this.. CTE is pretty powerfull!

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
  value, pk, id,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION  BY id order by id DESC)
    , rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, pk)
     FROM test
)
SELECT
  curr.rnk, prev.rnk, curr.rownum, prev.rownum, curr.pk, prev.pk, curr.id, prev.id, curr.value, prev.value, curr.value - prev.value
FROM CTE curr
INNER JOIN CTE prev on curr.rownum = prev.rownum -1 and curr.id = prev.id 
and curr.rnk <=1
```

Comment: From the tags, I hope the DB used is MySql and not MSSQL. And CTE is supported for MSSQL.

Comment: yes mysql, no cte. Thanks between will be surely helpful to some one else.